# Use JQuery next() and find() to find the next closest class-given element on a hovered div and show it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I am attempting to show/hide the next sub-nav element on mouse hover and mouse leave, but I can't get the right syntax for next() and find()... I have tried :

```
$(this).next('.sub-nav').show();

$(this).next('div').find('.sub-nav').show();
```

Neither has worked, I am pretty sure I just am using the wrong syntax. Is there something that I am missing, or another caveat I need to put in for Jquery to find the next 'sub-nav' under the preceding 'has-children' div?

```js
$('.has-children').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css({
      'border-bottom-right-radius': '0',
      'border-bottom-left-radius': '0'
    });
    $('.bottom-nav .sub-nav li:last-child').css({
      'border-bottom-right-radius': '10px',
      'border-bottom-left-radius': '10px'
    });

    $('.sub-nav').show();
  },
  function() {
    $(this).css({
      'border-bottom-right-radius': '10px',
      'border-bottom-left-radius': '10px'
    });
    $('.sub-nav').hide();
  });
```

```css
.bottom-nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  max-width: 912px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 22px;
}

.bottom-nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.bottom-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #4ea45a;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 225px;
  font-size: 16px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bottom-nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.bottom-nav .sub-nav {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 225px;
}

.bottom-nav .sub-nav li {
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 15px;
  background-color: #4ea45a;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bottom-nav .sub-nav li img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.bottom-nav .sub-nav li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.bottom-nav .sub-nav li a:hover,
.bottom-nav .sub-nav li a:active,
.bottom-nav ul li a:hover,
.bottom-nav ul li a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ebd3af;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bottom-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="has-children" style="padding-top:12px;">
      <a href="about">MENU 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="SUB">SUB 1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-children" style="padding-top:3px;">
      <a href="#">MENU 2</a>
      <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#">SUB2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `next` (immediate following **sibling**) that is a div or has class `.sub-nav'` so both will fail. But there's a `.sub-nav` child so `find`will work. In this case `.sub-nav` is a child of `.has-children`, so `.children()` would also work.

```js
    $('.has-children').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css({
        'border-bottom-right-radius': '0',
        'border-bottom-left-radius': '0'
      })
      .find('.sub-nav').show();

    $('.bottom-nav .sub-nav li:last-child').css({
      'border-bottom-right-radius': '10px',
      'border-bottom-left-radius': '10px'
    });
  },
  function() {
    $(this).css({
        'border-bottom-right-radius': '10px',
        'border-bottom-left-radius': '10px'
      })
      .find('.sub-nav').hide();
  });
```

```css
.bottom-nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  max-width: 912px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 22px;
}

.bottom-nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.bottom-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #4ea45a;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 225px;
  font-size: 16px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bottom-nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.bottom-nav .sub-nav {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 225px;
}

.bottom-nav .sub-nav li {
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 15px;
  background-color: #4ea45a;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bottom-nav .sub-nav li img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.bottom-nav .sub-nav li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.bottom-nav .sub-nav li a:hover,
.bottom-nav .sub-nav li a:active,
.bottom-nav ul li a:hover,
.bottom-nav ul li a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ebd3af;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bottom-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="has-children" style="padding-top:12px;">
      <a href="about">MENU 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="SUB">SUB 1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-children" style="padding-top:3px;">
      <a href="#">MENU 2</a>
      <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#">SUB2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```